# Normal spline line in blender

Tags: splines

Good afternoon. Is it possible to create a plug-in for the blender to create normal spline lines, which are the same as those in 3d max?

Comment: What is called the path, this is not a normal spaln. A straight line should have 2 points minimum and not 25 as it is now.

Comment: What about the current curve options doesn't suit your needs?

Comment: too many sinks are not needed after export..
There is an addon with which you can create a vertex and after it Extrude I want this, but only so that Extrude is applied atomically and the next point is created wherever I click.